# How to push data in mongoDB using method spread?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I’m trying to solve a problem by reducing my code. In function which sends object with data of the user during registration into the database of mongoDB. In my code I use express and mongoose. Code without the rest method works and there is no any error. In this part of the code route with the POST method passes data from ‘body’ to the function CallFunction: login, name, family, middleName, role, phone, email, password

```
const {login, name, family, middleName, role, phone, email, password } = req.body 
await registration.callFunction(login, name, family, middleName, role, phone, email, password, res).then(....)
```

This function accepts data, hashing a password and saves as object to mongo collection

```
async function callFunction(login, name, family, middleName, role, phone, email, password){ 
const mainData = mongoose.model('mainuserdatas', Schemas.SchemaUserData); 
const hashedPassword = await extFunc.hashPassword(password) 
const typeData = new mainData({ login, name, family, middleName, role, phone, email, password: hashedPassword }); 
return ... }
```

Mongoose schema for mongo

```
const SchemaUserData = new Schema({ 
login: String, 
name: String, 
family: String, 
middleName: String, 
role: String, 
phone: String, 
email: String, 
password: String, 
});
```

What i've tried:

I need to reduce quantity of arguments in the function by method …rest, but I can’t understand how to do it.
I tried to leave only the password argument, but others put in the …rest, but I can’t handle this method and send it to the collection but this way unsuccessful because i didnt handle and cant add data from array(...rest returns an array)

```
async function callFunction(password, ...rest){...}
```

How to handle data in the rest, add to object, set keys and send it to my collection? Also I tried wrap all arguments in routing in object:

```
await registration.fullUserData({login, name, family, middleName, role, phone, email, password}, res).then(... )
```

but it doesn’t work